# Textarea with New Lines after Comma Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am new to front-end development and I am trying to figure out the best approach to utilizing a text area that has a new line after each comma. I am really trying to figure out what the best approach would be in AngularJs(filter,Regex,etc.)

**Now:**

```
hello,how,are,you
```

**After:**

```
Hello
how
are
you
```

**currently:**

```
<textarea cols="105" rows="30" disabled="true"
          style="background-color: floralwhite; resize: none; white-space: normal; margin-top: 0px; border: none;">
    {{profile.exampleValues}}
</textarea>
```

I tried to write a filter with no luck:

```
.filter('newlines', function () {
     return function (text) {
         return text.replace(',', '<br/>');
     }
})
```

Comment: New line is `\n`, `<br/>` is an HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code to get it working.

First of all, `white-space: normal;` was replaced by `white-space: pre-line;`

Secondly, the filter was improved to deal with a regular expression. According to [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.
>
> Note: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

```
app.filter('newlines', function () {
  return function (text) {
    return text.replace(/,/g, '\n');
  };
});
```

As a result, the `textarea` should look like:

```
<textarea cols="105" rows="30" disabled="true"
          style="background-color: floralwhite; white-space: pre-line; resize: none; margin-top: 0px; border: none;">
    {{profile.exampleValues | newlines}}
</textarea>
```

Please look at the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FOckK672GiERb2JN9nrU?p=preview).